# What are some of the most useful yet little known features in the PowerShell language

Tags: powershell

A while back I was reading about multi-variable assignments in PowerShell. This lets you do things like this

```
64 >  $a,$b,$c,$d = "A four word string".split()

65 >  $a
A

66 >  $b
four
```

Or you can swap variables in a single statement

```
$a,$b = $b,$a
```

What little known nuggets of PowerShell have you come across that you think may not be as well known as they should be?

Comment: Andy, are you restricting this to PowerShell 1.0, or is 2.0 ok to discuss?

Comment: As people post ideas, it would be helpful to say which version (1/2) they are supported in.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `$$` command.  I often have to do repeated operations on the same file path.  For instance check out a file and then open it up in VIM.  The `$$` feature makes this trivial

```
PS> tf edit some\really\long\file\path.cpp
PS> gvim $$
```

It's short and simple but it saves a lot of time.

Comment: THere are a lot of great answers and I thank everyone who posted something up here. I chose this one for a couple reasons. I personally did not know about $$ and also it was the first answer. Thanks again to everyone who chimed in. Lots of great input!

Answer (score 19):

By far the most powerful feature of PowerShell is its [ScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock(VS.85).aspx) support. The fact that you can so concisely pass around what are effectively anonymous methods without any type constraints are about as powerful as C++ function pointers and as easy as C# or F# lambdas.

I mean how cool is it that using ScriptBlocks you can implement a "using" statement (which PowerShell doesn't have inherently). Or, pre-v2 you could even implement [try-catch-finally](http://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/archive/2007/10/10/powershell-try-catch-finally-comes-to-life.aspx).

```
function Using([Object]$Resource,[ScriptBlock]$Script) {
    try {
        &$Script
    }
    finally {
        if ($Resource -is [IDisposable]) { $Resource.Dispose() }
    }
}

Using ($File = [IO.File]::CreateText("$PWD\blah.txt")) {
   $File.WriteLine(...)
}
```

How cool is that!

Answer (score 15):

A feature that I find is often overlooked is the ability to pass a file to a switch statement.

Switch will iterate through the lines and match against strings (or regular expressions with the -regex parameter), content of variables, numbers, or the line can be passed into an expression to be evaluated as $true or $false

```
switch -file 'C:\test.txt' 
{   
  'sometext' {Do-Something}   
  $pwd {Do-SomethingElse}  
  42 {Write-Host "That's the answer."}  
  {Test-Path $_} {Do-AThirdThing}  
  default {'Nothing else matched'} 
}
```

Comment: I think Bruce's book pointed out that switch was one of the most powerful language constructs in PowerShell. Passing in a file is very cool. Thanks Steve.

Comment: That he did.. and I find the file part the most overlooked.  Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 13):

$OFS - [output field separator](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6957.entry). A handy way to specify how array elements are separated when rendered to a string:

```
PS> $OFS = ', '
PS> "$(1..5)"
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
PS> $OFS = ';'
PS> "$(1..5)"
1;2;3;4;5
PS> $OFS = $null # set back to default
PS> "$(1..5)"
1 2 3 4 5
```

[Always guaranteeing you get an array result](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!816.entry). Consider this code:

```
PS> $files = dir *.iMayNotExist
PS> $files.length
```

$files in this case may be $null, a scalar value or an array of values.  $files.length isn't going to give you the number of files found for $null or for a single file.  In the single file case, you will get the file's size!! Whenever I'm not sure how much data I'll get back I always enclose the command in an array subexpression like so:

```
PS> $files = @(dir *.iMayNotExist)
PS> $files.length # always returns number of files in array
```

Then $files will always be an array. It may be empty or have only a single element in it but it *will* be an array.  This makes reasoning with the result much simpler.

Array covariance support:

```
PS> $arr = '127.0.0.1','192.168.1.100','192.168.1.101'
PS> $ips = [system.net.ipaddress[]]$arr
PS> $ips | ft IPAddressToString, AddressFamily -auto

IPAddressToString AddressFamily
----------------- -------------
127.0.0.1          InterNetwork
192.168.1.100      InterNetwork
192.168.1.101      InterNetwork
```

[Comparing arrays using Compare-Object](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6159.entry):

```
PS> $preamble = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetPreamble()
PS> $preamble | foreach {"0x{0:X2}" -f $_}
0xEF
0xBB
0xBF
PS> $fileHeader = Get-Content Utf8File.txt -Enc byte -Total 3
PS> $fileheader | foreach {"0x{0:X2}" -f $_}
0xEF
0xBB
0xBF
PS> @(Compare-Object $preamble $fileHeader -sync 0).Length -eq 0
True
```

Fore more stuff like this, check out my free eBook - [Effective PowerShell](http://tinyurl.com/efposh).

Answer (score 10):

Along the lines of multi-variable assignments.

$list = 1,2,3,4

While($list) {
  $head, $list = $list
  $head
}

1
2
3
4

Comment: Here is a new an improved version: while($head, $list = $list) { $head } -- It is a nice array shifting technique

Answer (score 8):

I've been using this:

```
if (!$?) {  # if previous command was not successful
    Do some stuff
}
```

and I also use $_ (current pipeline object) quite a bit, but these might be more known than other stuff.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that many operators work on arrays as well and return the elements where a comparison is true or operate on each element of the array independently:

```
1..1000 -lt 800 -gt 400 -like "?[5-9]0" -replace 0 -as "int[]" -as "char[]" -notmatch "\d"
```

This is faster than `Where-Object`.

Answer (score 3):

Not a language feature but super helpful

`f8` -- Takes the text you have put in already and searches for a command that starts with that text.

Answer (score 3):

Tab-search through your history with #

Example:

PS> Get-Process explorer
PS> "Ford Explorer"
PS> "Magellan" | Add-Content "great explorers.txt"
PS> type "great explorers.txt"
PS> #expl *<-- Hit the <tab> key to cycle through history entries that have the term "expl"*

Answer (score 2):

Love this thread.  I could list a ton of things after reading Windows Powershell in Action.  There's a disconnect between that book and the documentation.  I actually tried to list them all somewhere else here, but got put on hold for "not being a question".

I'll start with foreach with three script blocks (begin/process/end):

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$sum=0} {$sum++} {$sum}
```

Speaking of swapping two variables, here's swapping two files:

```
${c:file1.txt},${c:file2.txt} = ${c:file2.txt},${c:file1.txt}
```

Search and replace a file:

```
${c:file.txt} = ${c:file.txt} -replace 'oldstring','newstring'
```

Using assembly and using namespace statements:

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
[messagebox]::show('hello world')
```

A shorter version of foreach, with properties and methods

```
ps | foreach name
'hi.there' | Foreach Split .
```

Use $() operator outside of strings to combine two statements:

```
$( echo hi; echo there ) | measure
```

Get-content/Set-content with variables:

```
$a = ''
get-content variable:a | set-content -value there
```

Anonymous functions:

```
1..5 | & {process{$_ * 2}}
```

Give the anonymous function a name:

```
$function:timestwo = {process{$_ * 2}}
```

Anonymous function with parameters:

```
& {param($x,$y) $x+$y} 2 5
```

You can stream from foreach () with these, where normally you can't:

```
& { foreach ($i in 1..10) {$i; sleep 1} } | out-gridview
```

Run processes in background like unix '&', and then wait for them:

```
$a = start-process -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'done a'} -PassThru
$b = start-process -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'done b'} -PassThru
$c = start-process -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'done c'} -PassThru
$a,$b,$c | wait-process
```

Or foreach -parallel in workflows:

```
workflow work {
  foreach -parallel ($i in 1..3) { 
    sleep 5 
    "$i done" 
  }
}

work
```

Or a workflow parallel block where you can run different things:

```
function sleepfor($time) { sleep $time; "sleepfor $time done"}

workflow work {
  parallel {
    sleepfor 3
    sleepfor 2
    sleepfor 1
  }
  'hi'
}

work
```

Three parallel commands in three more runspaces with the api:

```
$a =  [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript{sleep 5;'a done'}
$b =  [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript{sleep 5;'b done'}
$c =  [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript{sleep 5;'c done'}
$r1,$r2,$r3 = ($a,$b,$c).begininvoke()

$a.EndInvoke($r1); $b.EndInvoke($r2); $c.EndInvoke($r3) # wait
($a,$b,$c).Streams.Error # check for errors
($a,$b,$c).dispose() # cleanup
```

Parallel processes with invoke-command, but you have to be at an elevated prompt with remote powershell working:

```
invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost { sleep 5; 'hi' }
```

An assignment is an expression:

```
if ($a = 1) { $a } 
$a = $b = 2
```

Get last array element with -1:

```
(1,2,3)[-1]
```

Discard output with [void]:

```
[void] (echo discard me)
```

Switch on arrays and $_ on either side:

```
switch(1,2,3,4,5,6) {
  {$_ % 2} {"Odd $_"; continue}
  4 {'FOUR'}
  default {"Even $_"}
}
```

Get and set variables in a module:

```
'$script:count = 0
$script:increment = 1
function Get-Count { return $script:count += $increment }' > counter.psm1 # creating file

import-module .\counter.psm1

$m = get-module counter
& $m Get-Variable count
& $m Set-Variable count 33
```

See module function definition:

```
& $m Get-Item function:Get-Count | foreach definition
```

Run a command with a commandinfo object and the call operator:

```
$d = get-command get-date
& $d
```

Dynamic modules:

```
$m = New-Module {
  function foo {"In foo x is $x"}
  $x=2
  Export-ModuleMember -func foo -var x
}
```

flags enum:

```
[flags()] enum bits {one = 1; two = 2; three = 4; four = 8; five = 16}
[bits]31
```

Little known codes for the -replace operator:

```
$number Substitutes the last submatch matched by group number.
${name} Substitutes the last submatch matched by a named capture of the form (?).
$$ Substitutes a single "$" literal.
$& Substitutes a copy of the entire match itself.
$` Substitutes all the text from the argument string before the matching portion.
$' Substitutes all the text of the argument string after the matching portion.
$+ Substitutes the last submatch captured.
$_ Substitutes the entire argument string.
```

Demo of workflows surviving interruptions using checkpoints.  Kill the window or reboot.  Then start PS again.  Use get-job and resume-job to resume the job.

```
workflow test1 {
  foreach ($b in 1..1000) {
    $b
    Checkpoint-Workflow
  }
}
test1 -AsJob -JobName bootjob
```

Emacs edit mode.  Pressing tab completion lists all the options at once.  Very useful.

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs
```

Any command that begins with "get-", you can leave off the "get-":

```
date
help
```

End parsing `--%` and end of parameters `--` operators.

```
write-output --% -inputobject
write-output -- -inputobject
```

Tab completion on wildcards:

```
cd \pro*iles # press tab
```

Compile and import a C# module with a cmdlet inside, even in Osx:

```
Add-Type -Path ExampleModule.cs -OutputAssembly ExampleModule.dll
Import-Module ./ExampleModule.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate backwards over a sequence just use the `len` of the sequence with a 1 on the other side of the range:

```
foreach( x in seq.length..1) { Do-Something seq[x] }
```